# Optimising a sum of logs

Tags: optimization, asymptotics, convex-optimization

Let $N>1$ and
\begin{equation*}
f_N\left(l_1,\dots,l_{N-1}\right)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N-1}\left[l_i-\log\left(l_i\right)\right]-\sum_{0<j<i<N}\log\left(l_i-l_j\right)
\end{equation*}
Let $\left(l_1^{\left(0\right)},\dots,l_{N-1}^{\left(0\right)}\right)$ such that $0<l_1^{\left(0\right)}<\cdots<l_{N-1}^{\left(0\right)}$ minimize $f_N$. Then what is $l_{N-1}^{\left(0\right)}$ as a function of $N$. Even an asymptotic answer for large $N$ would be great.

This question came up in finding the equilibrium positions of a physical system.

I have already written a code to minimise this using gradient descent.